# How to disable radon high cyclomatic complexity check?

Tags: python, static-analysis, cyclomatic-complexity

Our codebase is checking high cyclomatic complexity using Radon. I have a function which is triggering this linter error, but I would like for it to pass the linter, similar to something like a pylint disable. Is there a way to do that with radon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Radon as a flake8 plugin, you can append `#  noqa R701` to the line with the function definition.

If you are using Radon standalone, there is no mechanism to skip a function or code block based on comments or any other markup - so, it is not possible.